# What is the largest number of pieces in a set for LEGO, Nanoblock, or any other brand?

Tags: building, shopping, set-identification, clone-brands, set-database

What is the largest number of pieces in a set for LEGO, Nanoblock, or any other brand?

I recently bought a 6800-piece LOZ Block set (Chinese Nanoblock knockoff).  I was wondering if there are sets in any block size or brand that have more pieces than that.

Answer (score 6):

The LEGO [World Map](https://www.lego.com/en-ca/product/world-map-31203) set has 11695 pieces.

[image: World Map box]

Comment: "Are we updating all the questions that ask this? I'm confident there's more than one." – If there is more than one question asking the same thing, most of them should probably be closed as duplicates. (If they're similar but not the same, they should probably not be closed, but perhaps edited to differentiate them from one another.) In any case, such meta-commentary probably should be left out of your answer itself.

Comment: While this is true for now I suggest to include [this link to Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets/query-45) that would always list sets with the most pieces. It would make this answer always relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Brickset has a query for sets with most pieces: [brickset.com/sets/query-45](http://brickset.com/sets/query-45)

Top of the list is Taj Mahal with 5922 pieces.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious update for this question is the LEGO 75192 Millenium Falcon with 7,541 pieces.

I wonder whether LEGO has plans for a 10k-piece set, maybe also the Millenium Falcon :)

Answer (score 1):

Largest Lego set apart from the world map is the 10,000 piece Eiffel Tower (technically 10,001 but that includes a brick separator). Followed by 9090 (Inc 3 brick separators) for the Titanic and 9036 (Inc 1 brick separator) for the Colosseum.

Answer (score 1):

TIWI Fantasy Castle = 6850 nano blocks. (Amazon)[image: Fantasy Castle]

Magic School, Nano Brick Harry Potter style castle - 6369. (eBay)
I found Swan Stone Castle on eBay = 11810.

Comment: Is 6850 the set number or the piece count? Adding a photo or a link to the set would help this post enormously.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not from the Lego camp, in terms of commercially released consumer sets. As far as I can remember, the Taj Mahal from 2008/9 had something around 5900 pieces, and is no longer available to buy new.

Comment: I was asking about any size or brand as the one i just bought from loz blocks  already has more pieces than that (6800)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Koyae European Castle](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Koyae-European-Castle-Architecture-Building/dp/B093C2T7DN?th=1) (Amazon URL) set that supposedly has 11,810 pieces. There are many clone sets that are advertised with many more pieces than they have, this one might be real according to the size of the build.

Answer (score -1):

There is a 11,800 nanoblock building Neuschwanstein Castle.

Comment: A picture or URL to official source would greatly befit this answer.

Comment: The box for Kawada Nanoblock Schloss Neuschwanstein says "over 5800 pieces" and does not support the 11,800 figure given in this answer. https://imgur.com/tZvN1f1

Comment: My googling was also unable to find such a set.

Comment: Careful with numbers on clone sets, there are quite a few around that claim 6,000+ pieces and reviewers say it’s only 600. No idea if it’s fraud or just cluelessness. I found one with downloadable instruction booklet that was clearly 2,000 parts according to the instructions instead of 6,000.

Comment: And try googling for “New Swan Stone” as well. :-( Seriously.